# Footer height get increased on every click on it

Tags: android, listview, footer

I have a footer which displays progress bar while fetching data and in case of any error it show as I click on footer to retry height get increased of footer in `ListView`

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Duplicate wording removed and highlighted important parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved it  i was adding new footer everytime i click on it.

So i just used `listview.getFooterViewsCount()` which returns number of footer  on listview so by this i resoved my answer